# Java interface inherits from two other interfaces - is it possible to, by using Java reflection, remove information about one of the interfaces?

Tags: java, reflection, vaadin-flow

I have this specific requirement due to the fact that a third-party library somehow has this `interface A` which `extends B`, which in turn `extends C, D`.

Now, the problem is that `interface C extends D`. IMO, since `C` already extends `D`, `B` should only `extends C`.

The issue arises when I try to use object of type `interface A` to bind a form in Vaadin Flow. The error message is: `Duplicate key found for property [this common method]`.

I inspected the object and noticed there is the following hierarchy:

```
       // myObject:
       //   reflectionData:
       //     referent:
       //       interfaces:
       //         [0]:
       //           name: "com.example...." [interface B from above]
       //           reflectionData:
       //             referent:
       //               interfaces:
       //                 [0]:
       //                   name: "com.example..." [interface C from above]
       //                 [1]:
       //                   name: "com.example..." [interface D from above]
```

My idea was to somehow, by using Java reflection maybe, remove the second element of the array (`interface D`) (if it's possible, that is), before sending the object to Vaadin's `Binder` class.

Comment: Hi, as you found a duplicate key for ... why not select the needed one ?

Comment: Are you sure the inheritance of the protocols are as you describe them because it doesn't make sense. Does B really implement/extend _both_ C and D?

Comment: @GweltazNiquel I'm not sure I understand the question. The error happens at a later stage, when the object with duplicate key is already sent to Vaadin. If I am able to remove this second interface from the object, I guess then Vaadin wouldn't find this duplicate property.

Comment: @JoakimDanielson Yes, I'm sure. I already shared this with the authors, hoping the second (D) is unnecessary and that they would update the code. But it's unlikely.

Comment: I would try to duplicate the object then cast choosed referent interface to D before sending it to Vaadin but we have too few code sample to guess how to intercept.

Comment: @JoakimDanielson I actually got it wrong the first time - it's corrected now. Please, take a look!

Answer (score 1):

You cannot modify reflection information in Java. But in fact, it is a bug in Vaadin, file a bug report. In Java, interface methods with same name (and parameters) are not considered duplicated - it is the same method. When java compiler doubts, it issues an error. If your program have been compiled, it is correct, and Vaadin must work with any correct program.